# Automation of Power Query data extract (bypass login or store password)

Tags: query, integration, automation, excel

I have a report built in Excel that links into other data sets that I can't upload to Salesforce, so I need to join the data with other sources using power query.

Unfortunately I'm unable to automate the report (using VBA) to run at scheduled intervals as Salesforce requires me to log in every time I refresh the query.

Is there a way I can disable that option in my Salesforce account settings, or enter the password via VBA so it works without manual intervention?

Thanks,

Oliver

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce does not allow the disabling of passwords (and that's a very good thing). Storing credentials is also problematic from a security perspective.

What you'll want to do here is create a Connected App in your target Salesforce org, and set it up to use Digital Signatures (so you need to have an X509 certificate with an RSA256 keypair. It can be a self-signed cert if necessary).

Once you have that in place, you'll be able to use the [JWT Bearer flow (OAuth 2.0)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5) to authenticate with Salesforce. That gives you an access token which you'll then include in the subsequent requests that your script is making.

The JWT flow is non-interactive (i.e. it doesn't need a popup window for the user to "interact" by providing their username and password), which is what you need when using a script to access Salesforce.

Do note you'll need to go through an interactive flow that generates a refresh token (like the web server flow) before you'll be able to use the JWT flow. All that really entails is:

- Using a browser to navigate to `https://(login|test).salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<connected app's consumer key>&redirect_uri=<whatever callback url you defined in the connected app>& response_type=code`
- it's `https://login.salesforce.com...` for your production environment, and `https://test.salesforce.com...` for sandboxes
- Entering your credentials
- Clicking the 'Allow' button to let your connected app perform requests on your behalf